# React Context State Is Not Updating When Trying to Use Token From Cookies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, react-hooks, react-context

It is my understanding that the most common way of persisting context state in a React web app is to store the user’s information in something like a token in local storage or a cookie, and then, on each page load, retrieving the token and setting the context state again, since state doesn’t persist between page loads.

That is what the vast majority of articles and SO answers have instructed me to do and I’ve tried to implement it here:

```
export const AuthProvider = ({children}: AuthContextProviderType) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>(null);
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [isValidated, setIsValidated] = useState(false);

    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    useEffect(() => {        
        var auth = cookies.filter(cookie => {            
            return cookie.split("=")[0].includes("authorization")
        })
        
        if (auth.length !== 0) {
            setIsAuthenticated(true);      
            var userInfo = jwt.decode(auth[0].split("=")[1])      
            setUser(userInfo)            
        }
    }, [])

    const values = {
        user,
        setUser,
        isAuthenticated,
        setIsAuthenticated,
        isValidated,
        setIsValidated,
    }
 
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={values}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

The problem is that my state is not updating when I need it to. After I log myself in and I am in my user dashboard, which is a protected route, I refresh the page and I’m kicked out to the login screen, meaning that my context that determines whether I can go to protected routes is not being updated. The user state is not updated either, of course.

I have also tried skipping the context step and going straight to the token to determine if a user can visit a protected route. However, this has not worked either:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cookies = document.cookie-split(";");
    const token = cookies[cookies. length - 1].split(",");

    console.log (token);

    if (token[0].split("=").includes("authorization")) {
       setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }
  }, [])

return(
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/request-access" element={<RequestAccess />} />
    // protected routes
    <Route path="/verify-email" element={
      <ProtectedRoute isRouteAccessible={isAuthenticated}>
        <VerifyEmail/>
      </ProtectedRoute>
    }
    />
  </Routes>
)
```

It might be worth mentioning that for some reason, my state does update immediately when set like this:

```
await axios.post(url + "login", payload)
        .then(res => {
            var token = jwt.decode(res.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]);                               
            context.setUser(token.User);
            context.setIsAuthenticated(true);
            console.log(context)
            document.cookie = `authorization=${res.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]}`            
            resolve('Success');
        })
        .catch(err => {     
            console.log(err);           
            reject("bad request")
        })
```

To summarize, I simply need a way to update and persist a user’s data a boolean that states the user has been verified, so a user can be “logged in”.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're refreshing, `isAuthenticated` initially is set to false. So, initial render is false. At that time, `isRouteAccessible` will return false.

`useEffect` will run after that render, so `isAuthenticated` then becomes true if cookies are there. But by this time, the url is/has already been changed to some public path.

So, you need to set `isAuthenticated`, with true or false, at the initial render only. You can pass a callback to useState for getting the initial value.

I created a [SandBox using localStorage](https://codesandbox.io/s/protected-route-refresh-issue-6ffzsj?file=/src/AuthContext.js) to implement the same. Please go through that, if you have doubts.

Try something like this.

```js
const initialState = () => {
  const cookies = document.cookie - split(";");
  const token = cookies[cookies.length - 1].split(",");

  console.log(token);

  if (token[0].split("=").includes("authorization")) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(initialState);
```

Refer to this answer as well, it has been explained there as well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70764325/6065749

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this approach to store the user's info (e.g. name, email) in my context as well and it worked like a charm. However, I have a quick question: when I log out, I still get errors because the references to my context can't actually find any context (since it was just deleted), even though I'm on the home page, which doesn't have any references to the context. If I could just have a little bit of direction on what do to about this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: @FordBurgess If possible, can you create a sandbox with the errors coming, when it's being deleted?Then I would be able to help you better.